# Ruby command line program that saves and updates users/preferences

Tags: ruby, file, parsing, command-line, stdin

I'm building an application that takes in stdin to save a user and their preferences. Should I write the stdin to a text file and save the user input there?

**commandline.rb**

```
class CommandLine
   def initialize(filename)
      @file = File.open(filename, 'w')   
   end

   def add_user(input)
      @file = File.open('new_accounts.txt', 'r+')
      @file.write(input)
      puts input
   end

   def run
      puts "Welcome to the Command Line Client!"
      command = ''
      while command != 'quit'
      printf "enter command: "
      input = gets.chomp
      parts = input.split
      command = parts[0]
      case command
          when 'quit' then puts 'Goodbye!'
          when '-a'   then add_user(parts[1..-1].join(" "))
          else
            puts 'Invalid command #{command}, please try again.'
          end
      end
   end
end

a = CommandLine.new('new_accounts.txt')
a.run
```

Let's say I want the user to enter '**-a tommy likes apples**' in the command line, I want it to output:

```
tommy likes apples
```

The same user tommy could also input '**-a tommy likes oranges**' which would then update his previous preference:

```
tommy likes oranges
```

Any help/direction is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for examples of reading the file as well?

Comment: You could save the information to a text file, but, HOW that data is stored is what is important. Don't save it in CSV or a single row per user. Instead, use Ruby's YAML or JSON classes to write the data in a more universal format, that is easily parsed and reused. Really though, I'd use a database of some sort, making it possible to create/read/update/delete user information without totally reading in, or overwriting the user file each time. Look at SQLite with [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) as a starting place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with using a text file if you are doing something simple. Alternatives are many and without more detail I'm afraid I can't make a good recommendation.

```
def add_user(input)
  File.open('new_accounts.txt', 'w') {|file| 
      file.write(input) 
  }
  puts input
end
```

FYI: This will make it so that your text file updates. :-)

**EDIT**: Changed the add_user method.

Comment: Why use `@` instance variables inside a method? Why not use `File.open` with a block, which is idiomatic Ruby so the file is automatically closed? Why write to a file with `r+` permission when `File.write` or `File.open` with the `w` mode is preferable? What will happen if there is more than one occurrence of the same user's information?

Comment: I merely added to what the OP had in his code. I will update. Good point with the more than one occurrence I should have verified more with the OP prior to answering.

Comment: I will try using Sequel; the problem asks for simplicity and thus I thought using a DB might be overkill for this command line application. Thanks for the input guys, will update the question as I go along.